# pySimpleGUI two filebrowser events were reversed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

Why the sg.filebrowser were reversed on my code? when I select CUSID file then then event is SPlist and when I select SPlist file then it is cusid event...

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('SystemDefaultForReal')
layout = [                  
[sg.FileBrowse('CUSID',size = (15,2),file_types =('Excel File', '*.xlsx'), key='cusid', enable_events=True, tooltip='cusid'), 
    sg.FileBrowse('SPECIAL PRICE LIST',size = (18,2),file_types =('Excel File', '*.xlsx'), key='SPlist', enable_events=True)],
[sg.Button('Convert', key='submit'), sg.Button("Cancel", k='cancel')],
[sg.StatusBar('', size=(50,1), key='status', justification='center'), sg.Button('Replace Header', key='-replace-', visible=False), sg.Button('Replace Headers', key='-replace2-', visible=False)]   
]
window = sg.Window("Special Price Converter", layout, element_justification='center', finalize=True, icon=r'C:\Python\apps\specialpriceconvert\icon.ico')
while True:
    event, values = window.read() 
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'cancel'):
        break
    elif 'cusid' in event: #if CUSID is selected
            window['status'].update(event)
    elif 'SPlist' in event:
        window['status'].update(event)            
window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

> The FileBrowse, FolderBrowse, FileSaveAs , FilesSaveAs, CalendarButton, ColorChooserButton buttons all fill-in values into another element located on the window. The target can be a Text Element or an InputText Element or the button itself. The location of the element is specified by the target variable in the function call.
>
> The default value for target is (ThisRow, -1). ThisRow is a special value that tells the GUI to use the same row as the button. The Y-value of -1 means the field one value to the left of the button. For a File or Folder Browse button, the field that it fills are generally to the left of the button is most cases. (ThisRow, -1) means the Element to the left of the button, on the same row.

No option `target` in `FileBrowse`, it will set the target to the previous element at the same row, or last one element if no previous element.

Set the option target to itself, like

```py
    [sg.FileBrowse('CUSID', target='cusid', size = (15,2),file_types =(('Excel File', '*.xlsx'),), key='cusid', enable_events=True, tooltip='cusid'),
     sg.FileBrowse('SPECIAL PRICE LIST', target='SPlist',size = (18,2),file_types =(('Excel File', '*.xlsx'),), key='SPlist', enable_events=True)],
```

Note: The option `file_types` should be in format `tuple of tuple`, so not `('Excel File', '*.xlsx')`, but `(('Excel File', '*.xlsx'),)`.